# Count datetime intervals which contains timestamp with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables:

A calendar table with both dates and hours.

[image: Calendar table]

And a table that contains incidents, with start time and end time in addition to set of attributes (only one, incident_code, in the example table).

[image: Incident table]

For a specific date range, I want to show how many incidents occurred each hour.

[image]

The following measure works, but struggles when the incident table becomes large and there is several slicers

```
incidentCnt = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(incidents);
    FILTER(
        incidents;
        incidents[start_datetime] < MAX(date_hour[datetime]) &&
            incidents[end_datetime] > MAX(date_hour[datetime])
    )
)
```

What would be a more efficient way to calculate this with DAX in Power BI?

EDIT: This expression will work with the data presented above (minor edits to the accepted answer).

```
Expanded_Incidents = 
GENERATE(
    incidents;
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        GENERATESERIES(
            DATE(
                YEAR(incidents[start_datetime]);
                MONTH(incidents[start_datetime]);
                DAY(incidents[start_datetime])
            ) + TIME(HOUR(incidents[start_datetime]);0;0);
            incidents[end_datetime];
            TIME(1;0;0)
        );
        "Expanded_incident_time"; [Value]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more effectiv way would be to expand the incidents table so that each incident occurs for each time between the start and end datetime. This you can do with a calculated table like this:

```
Expanded_Incidents = 
GENERATE(
    incidents;
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        GENERATESERIES(
            incidents[start_date];
            incidents[end_date];
            TIME(h;m;s)
        );
        "Expanded_incident_time"; [Value]
    )
)
```

Change the `TIME(h;m;s)` to the time resolution of your choosing.

Then make a relationship between your dateTime dim table and the `[Expanded_incident_time]` column (this should be a 1:*). Then you only have to make a measure which counts the number of rows in the new table. This will give you the number of active incidents during a specific time and I believe it will be faster than reitterating over the table each time.

Comment: This gives massive speed up and works even with large data sets. I tried with 10 000 000 rows in my incident table, and even added two more attributes with 10 000 and 380 000 distinct values. The resulting Expanded_Incidents table then had 69 762 000 rows. It took some time to load but the report was very responsive. I also tried expanding the incident table with power query, which worked fine, but resulted in a much larger *.pbi file (430MB vs 200MB). Not sure why.